# OS X Lion - download once and install on multiple computers

Tags: data-transfer, macos

I have multiple computers which I will be installing Lion on. Is it possible to download it once and install on those computers?

Comment: Since Lion is yet to be officially released and its license is therefore unknown, I don't think this question can be answered yet. The current developer release is linked to one Apple ID and can be installed on multiple computers, but whether the same will be true (legally) of the final version is yet to be seen. Vote to close.

Comment: Not a guaranteed answer for the release, but it's very likely to be possible: http://www.tuaw.com/2011/06/07/how-to-burn-a-lion-boot-disc/

Comment: The details of how the beta is being distributed is no guarantee how the final download will happen. Currently, no MAS product allows the installer to be visible to the end user so something would have to change for this to be possible.

Comment: We should re-open this now that OS X Lion is retail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instructions taken from the following URL: http://www.tuaw.com/2011/06/07/how-to-burn-a-lion-boot-disc/

- Use Finder to locate the Mac OS X Lion installer, right-click and select "Show Package Contents."
- Find the SharedSupport folder and look for a file named "InstallESD.dmg." This is the Lion Boot Disc image.
- Copy the "InstallESD.dmg" file to another folder, such as your desktop.
- Launch Disk Utility and click the burn button.
- Select the "InstallESD.dmg" copy as the image to burn, insert a DVD, and in a few minutes, you will have a brand new Lion Boot Disc.

Comment: Additional (hossibly useful) info: http://www.tuaw.com/2011/06/08/how-to-install-lion-from-an-sd-card/

Comment: Will this work to perform a full install - e.g. onto a machine with a clean harddrive?

Answer (score 3):

It will be, as announced on WWDC 2011 keynote.
It will be delivered via the App Store for $29, and you can use it to update your other authorized Macs as well.
I'm not to keen with the details. Sorry.

Link to the keynote:
http://events.apple.com.edgesuite.net/11piubpwiqubf06/event/

Comment: IIRC the keynote said you could buy once via the store and use it on multiple macs. It didn't say you could download it on one mac and then use that download to upgrade multiple machines. I really hope you can though, I'm not that excited to download 4gb via wireless to my "set top box" mac mini when i already have a copy on my MBP via ethernet and several perfectly good memory sticks!

Answer (score 1):

Since it complies to the same rules as other mac apps, you only need to buy Lion once.

At least that is what I recall from seeing the WWCD video.

Comment: ... and what about the software licence? I think you mean "you only need to *download* Lion once."